# Why is the square root of -Infinity +Infinity in Java?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, ieee-754

I tried two different ways to find the square root in Java:

```
Math.sqrt(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY); // NaN
Math.pow(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0.5); // Infinity
```

Why doesn't the second way return the expected answer which is `NaN` (same as with the first way)?

Comment: Getting the square root of something negative is not defined. If it does not result in some error handling behaviour, like throwing, I'd consider it undefined behaviour, and thus allow the compiler to summon nasal demons as you'd say in C.

Comment: @Aziuth: the behavior of both `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow` is fully defined even for negative arguments, and "undefined behavior" isn't a concept Java borrowed from C (fortunately). Java has what the C standard would call implementation-defined and unspecified behavior in some very select cases, but no worse than that.

Comment: Ah, one of those "why designers, designed it this way? I would totally do it differently!" questions. They cannot be objectively answered by anyone but the designers...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367011/why-is-pow-infinity-positive-non-integer-infinity

Comment: @Aziuth: ***Nothing*** in IEEE754 is undefined; and for good reason, due to Floating Point being an inexact representation of the Real Numbers. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html#pgfId-674) for more details.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: I beg to differ - IEEE754 is ***very well*** thought out, addressing not only efficiency concerns of great importance 40 years ago, but the need to be able, at times, to continue computations even in the occurrence of overflow and invalid operations.

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue32171, where almost the exact same issue was raised for Python. Turns out that this behaviour is *not* specified in IEEE 754, but that the omission is either accidental or due to the IEEE 754 folks thinking it was obvious enough not to need specification. See also: http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/msg03969.html

Comment: @jpa: Looks close enough to be a duplicate, to me. (And I think the accepted answer there is a good one.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I wouldn't say it's "very well thought out".  There are some good engineering decisions, but some horrible ones as well.  One of the most important concepts in mathematics is the equivalence relation, but IEEE-754 provides no clean and efficient way to test whether two values x and y are equivalent (evaluating `x==y || (x!=x && y!=y)` seems neither clean nor efficient).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A ***NaN*** is returned (under IEEE 754) in order to continue a computation when a truly undefined (intermediate) result has been obtained. An ***infinity*** is returned in order to continue a computation after an overflow has occurred.

Thus the behaviour

```
Math.sqrt(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY); // NaN
```

is specified because it is known (easily ***and quickly***) that an undefined value has been generated; based solely on the sign of the argument.

However evaluation of the expression

```
Math.pow(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0.5); // Infinity
```

encounters both an overflow AND an invalid operation. However the invalid operation recognition is critically dependent on how accurate the determination of the second argument is. If the second argument is the result of a prior rounding operation, then it may not be ***exactly*** 0.5. Thus the less serious determination, recognition of an overflow, is returned in order to avoid critical dependence of the result on the accuracy of the second argument.

Additional details on some of the reasoning behind the IEEE 754 standard, including the reasoning behind returning flag values instead of generating exceptions, is available in

[***What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*** (1991, David Goldberg)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html#pgfId-674),

which is Appendix D of

[**Sun Microsystems Numerical Computation Guide**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/).

Comment: Well, if the second argument is not exactly 0.5, then complex phase of the resulting infinity is still not even close to `Pi*N`, so mathematically, it's still invalid operation (for an R→R function). Thus this doesn't seem to be a good enough explanation for why it doesn't generate a NaN.

Comment: @Ruslan: I disagree. If the second argument is supposed to be exactly 2/3, passed in as ~0.6666666667, then the correct return value is **Overflow** rather than **NaN**.

Comment: Well this depends on the choice of branch cuts... they could have chosen to have a complex result (e.g. `DirectedInfinity[-0.4999999998186198 + 0.8660254038891585*I]`) from this and thus return NaN. I suppose they chose instead that if there's a chance to get a real result, then it should be returned...

Comment: I find the argument here questionable. In particular, it's missing an explanation of (a) why the possible inexactness of the second argument makes a difference (*why* should we consider `pow(-inf, 0.5+epsilon)` to be `inf` rather than `nan`?), and (b) an explanation of what's special about `-inf`: `pow(-10.0, y)` gives a `nan` for *any* non-integer finite `y`. I think it's much more likely that the rationale comes simply from the behaviour of `pow(-0.0, y)`, the desire to preserve the symmetry `pow(1/x, y) == 1/pow(x, y)`, and the fact that `1/-0.0` is `-inf`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I counter that my presentation not only implies your symmetry argument, but also explains why an **infinity** symmetry is chosen to be preserved rather than the **NaN** symmetry that is also available.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: You say "the less serious determination [...] is returned in order to avoid critical dependence of the result on the accuracy of the second argument". What _is_ this dependence you're avoiding? You seem to be imagining some hypothetical alternative result where `pow(-inf, 0.5)` and `pow(-inf, 0.5+epsilon)` return different results. But the obvious alternative is to return `nan` for both an exact `0.5` and an "inexact" 0.5; you don't explain why this inexactness is important. Maybe you could clarify the answer?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: There are countably many real numbers (ie all the rationals with an odd denominator > 1 in reduced form) that, when the exponent of a negative real number, produce at least one real result. But NONE of those countably many values can be EXACTLY expressed by a IEEE754 floating point expression. None-the-less, when the 1st argument is `-inf` then the `Math.Pow(,)` function will ALWAYS overflow in magnitude (your symmetry argument restated), regardless of whether a real result might exist or not for a finite first argument.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Is there any non-integer value of x for which Math.Pow(-8.0,x) should sensibly yield a positive value?  Certainly a positive result should be expected if x is any even integer, and a negative result if x is any odd integer, but if x isn't an integer value I don't see any number as being sensible.  Personally, I subscript to the notion that Pow(double, int) and Pow(double, double) are fundamentally different operations, and it is perfectly reasonable to say that the second is defined only if the first operand is positive, regardless of whether the second happens to...

Comment: ...be a whole number.  I think FORTRAN specified things that way, and it seems more reasonable than the alternative.  Such a specification would also make clear that Pow(anyValue, 0) is unambiguously 1.0, while Pow(0.0, 0.0) and Pow(anyInfinity, 0.0) and Pow(NaN, 0.0) should both be NaN.

Comment: @supercat: Yes; x = +2/3 yields +4.0. Unfortunately, it is impossible to represent 2/3 exactly in floating point representation due to the odd denominator.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Are there any representable value of x for which `Math.Pow(-8.0,x)` should sensibly yield a positive value?  The mathematical function `f(x) = (-8)**x` is discontinuous everywhere.  It may make sense to define it for exact values of x where its value is a real number, but it doesn't converge in a way that would render an approximate value meaningful anywhere else.

Comment: Another interesting URL is http://floating-point-gui.de/ and that URL is easy to remember

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Great. Did u find this from the links you mentioned above ? It's good to know any such references somewhere, useful to clear understanding of computations.

Comment: @Pratik: I applied my knowledge; experience; and understanding of arithmetic and mathematical calculation to the information and description (of both motive and method) contained in the links provided.

Answer (score 30):

It is just acting as is described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) of `Math`.

For `Math.sqrt`:

> If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.

For `Math.pow`:

> If
>
> - the first argument is negative zero and the second argument is less than zero but not a finite odd integer, or
> - the first argument is negative infinity and the second argument is greater than zero but not a finite odd integer,
>
> then the result is positive infinity.

As to why they made that design choice - you'll have to ask the authors of java.

Comment: I agree, but should not be inconsistency in using different methods, especially when it comes to Math, there has to be a standard answer, isn't it ? From my perception, second method is returning incorrect answer.

Comment: from my own personnal point of view, both are wrong. You should throw an exception, not returning a value like Nan or Infinity.

Comment: @Pratik: the return values of `Math.pow()` align with the C standard definition of `pow()`. It seems likely that they both align with the IEEE 754 definition of the operation, but I have no copy of the standard handy. The IEEE 754 designers have very detailed reasons for why things are the way they are, though not always comprehensible by mere mortals.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, I have thought of IEEE 754 too, but I didn't know whether the standard also defines the actual operations. If someone had access to it it would be good to have additional information from there.

Comment: @Pratik: You can only say that because you ***know*** that the second argument is exact. The Floating Point specification has to allow for the possibility that the second argument is an approximation (either an estimate or the result of a prior operation), and thus that while an *overflow* definitely occurs, an invalid operation only ***might*** have occurred.

Comment: The question is not about whether it obeys the documenation, but about the why. In that sense, the answer by @PieterGeerkens does a better job.